# Update pull requests (add commits)

Tags: git, github, pull-request

How can I update pull requests?
I tried it over and over but all I get is another pull request!
P.S. I don´t want to do it with git bash!

Comment: @Simon not a duplicate because I said NOT with git bash

Comment: Anselm if by "git bash" you mean the cli ("git bash" is not a thing) - then just use a gui that does the same thing as any commands in the duplicate questions. If you want help with how to push/pull/commit using a particular git gui - you need to point out which gui it is you're using. `I tried it` - what did you do?

Answer (score 2):

I think if you just add more commits to the local feature branch that you have used as a pull request the get added to the pending pull-request.

Answer (score 1):

Just commit changes on local branch and push it to the remote.